# Creating a Complex Header Layout in JQGrid and Colors in Cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

I have table that needs to be implemented which has a complex layout of headers and color coding in the cells. Can someone suggest how to achieve the layout ?[image: Required Layout for the Layout Grid]

Kindly provide your inputs .

Answer (score 0):

The complex layout was achieved using the grouping the header information . Refer the following link to see the official documentation :

[[http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar][1]](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agroupingheadar%5d%5b1%5d)

And to get the colors in the header : I used HTML tags with custom CSS to give a similar look and feel .